# God/Goddess of clones or duplicates

Tags: myth-identification, mythical-creatures

Is there any god/goddess who had the power of clones or represented them?
Like Dionysus is a god of wine and many other related things, is there a god of clones/duplicates/mirror images across any mythology? Even a monster or creature is ok.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twins_in_mythology

Comment: this works. But I was searching for something for twins/clones.  ex: Ares is the Greek god of war, Similarly I wanted to find a god/goddess of twins/clones. Thanks for answering.

Comment: As @tom said, I don't think there's is any god for this. Because gods are imagined to explain natural phenomenon like thunder etc. But I never saw a clone or anything being cloned. If you find a god of [starfish](http://www.starfishfacts.org/regeneration_and_self_cloning.html) or of [earthworms](https://animals.howstuffworks.com/animal-facts/earthworm3.htm), this may be your only option. But I still think nobody in theses times cared about those species enough to create a cult or so.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**To answer your question if there is a god specifically for clones, the answer would be no.**

Since there was no such thing as cloning in ancient times they did not have a deity or creature for it (just like there is no such thing as an ancient god of automobiles or smartphones).

Although some creatures and deities have the power to clone themselves a specific god for cloning does not exist. If you where to search for a duplicitous deity of creature the list would be substantially bigger.

The closest answer to be found is the Hindu [Raktabīja](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raktab%C4%ABja)

> In Hindu mythology, Raktabīja was an [Asura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asura) (loosely translated as
> demon) who fought with [Shumbha and Nishumbha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sumbha_and_Nisumbha) against Goddess [Durga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durga) and
> Goddess [Kali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kali) or Goddess [Chamunda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chamunda). Raktabīja had a boon that whenever a
> drop of his blood fell on the ground, **a duplicate** Raktabīja would be
> born at that spot (rakta=blood, bīja=seed; " **He for whom each drop of
> blood is a seed**"). According to some sources, Raktabija was, in his
> previous birth, [Rambhasura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rambha_(asura)), king of demons and the father of
> [Mahishasura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahishasura).
>
> The eighth chapter of the [Devi Mahatmya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devi_Mahatmya), RaktabIja-vadh, focuses on
> Ambika's battle with Raktabīja as part of her battle against the
> Asuras Shumbha and Nishumbha, who had disenfranchised the gods from
> heaven. Raktabīja was wounded, but drops of blood falling on the
> ground created innumerable other Raktabījas, and [Ambika](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambika_(goddess)) and the
> [Matrikas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrikas) were in difficulty.
>
> At this point, the Goddess Kali joined
> the battle, who stretched her tongue over the earth and licked up each
> drop of blood pouring from Raktabīja's body while other goddesses
> wounded him. Kali devoured his **duplicates** into her gaping mouth. This
> form who drank the demon's blood is also called Raktheshwari.

Illustrated below is the Goddess Ambika Leading the Eight Mother Goddesses in Battle Against the Demon Raktabija. Notice Kali using her tongue to collect the dead duplicates of Raktabija while more are coming from the right.

[image: The Goddess Ambika Leading the Eight Mother Goddesses in Battle Against the Demon Raktabija, Folio from a Devimahatmya (Glory of the Goddess), early 18th century..Several Sanskrit words and phrases are inscribed across the work]

Comment: To be picky, "* no such thing as cloning in ancient times*" isn't quite true in general.  People have cloned plants since the beginning of agriculture, and fishermen used to inadvertently clone starfish (they'd tear them up to kill them, but each piece would then grow into a full starfish).